# Laravel eager load model from a hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

There are 3 tables:

`users`: id, name

`compliments`: id, name

`users_compliments`: id, compliment_id, user_id, complimentor_id

Here is my User model:

```
class User extends Model
    public function sent_compliments()  {  
        return 
            $this->belongsToMany(
            'Compliment', 
            'users_compliments', 
            'complimentor_id',
            'compliment_id'
         )->withPivot('user_id');
}
```

here is an example response if I run `$user->sent_compliments()->get()`

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
     all: [
       Compliment {
         id: 2,
         name: "You are smart",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
           user_id: 6,
           id: 99,
         },
       },
       Compliment {
         id: 52,
         name: "You are funny",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
           user_id: 42,
           id: 186,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

but here is the response I want (it includes the actual User model instead of just the user_id in the pivot)

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
     all: [
       Compliment {
         id: 2,
         name: "You are smart",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
           user_id: 6,
           id: 99,
         },
         user {
             id: 6,
             name: "John"
         }
       },
       Compliment {
         id: 52,
         name: "You are funny",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
           user_id: 42,
           id: 186,
         },
           user {
             id: 42,
             name: "Alex"
         }
       },
     ],
   }
```

Is there a way to get this data with an eloquent eager load (like using the `With::` command ) instead of iterating through the pivot, collecting the user_ids and manually querying the `User` table?

Comment: please show `sent_nominations` method

Comment: The `sent_compliments` method is posted in the question above. It's in the `User` model. `public function sent_compliments()` @Alihosseinshahabi

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi sorry, there was a typo in my question. `sent_nominations` does not exist. It should be `sent_compliments` ... I just updated the question and I apologize for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `pivot` class and add relation `belongsTo` to pivot model for user_id

**User Model**

```
public function sent_compliments()  {  
    return 
        $this->belongsToMany(
        'Compliment', 
        'users_compliments', 
        'complimentor_id',
        'compliment_id'
     )->withPivot('user_id')->using('App\UserComplement');
}
```

**Pivot model** 
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

```
class UserComplement extends Pivot {
    protected $table = 'users_compliments';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Feth data**

```
//if you have user instance already then
$complements = $user->sent_compliments;

//if you don't have fetched user yet then try this 
$user = User::with('sent_compliments')->find($userId);
$complements = $user->sent_compliments;

foreach($complements as $complement){
    dd($complement);
    dd($complement->pivot->user);
}
```

For details check this **Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

**EDIT**

As @JonasStaudenmeir pointed, there is no way to eager load `pivot user` relationship. Here is another solution

**User Model**

```
public function sent_compliments()  {  
    return $this->hasMany(UserCompliment::class , 'complimentor_id');
}
```

**UserComplement model**

```
class UserComplement extends Model {
    $table = 'users_compliments';

    public function complimentor()  {  
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'complimentor_id');
    }

    public function complement()  {  
        return $this->belongsTo(Compliment::class , 'compliment_id');
    }

    public function user()  {  
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Fetch Data**

```
$user = User::with('sent_compliments','sent_compliments.complement', 'sent_compliments.user')->find($userId);
$sentComplements = $user->sent_compliments;

foreach($sentComplements as $sentComplement){
    dd($sentComplement->complement);
    dd($sentComplement->user);
}
```

Hope it may clear you

Comment: thanks for your help, but this didn't work... the one and only difference is that the response now says `pivot: UserNominationPivot` instead of `pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` ... but the `user` model is still not in the response

Comment: you have imported wrong `Pivot` class, it is a tested code. let me add the pivot import class there

Comment: i have added import, use it in your code and then try

Comment: how did you fetch the `User` model ?

Comment: you must have to create `UserComplement` class with extending `Pivot` and add it in relation like this `->using('App\UserComplement');'

Comment: There is no way to eager load the `user` relationship.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thanks for pointing, i have updated with alternative solution